# Open Package.swift or generate-xcodeproj

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm confused on something, basically the difference between `open Package.swift` and generating an Xcode project with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

Looking at Apple's own repo for swift-argument-parser, if I `open Package.swift`, I can use Xcode, but I don't have what I'm traditionally used to like seeing the targets in the General Tab. (this screenshot is with generating an xcodeproj):

[image]

Even though these are targets that are defined in Package.swift, you don't
see them if you just use `open Package.swift`. Screenshot below:

[image]

If I want to create a FAT framework or an XCFramework for clients not using SPM, it seems like using an Xcode project with `xcodebuild` is still needed, right?

Comment: I think you should use none of it, I explained about the compilation process and folder hierarchy of an SPM project here (with example and tests in a single project): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758546/can-i-specify-a-platform-target-when-running-swift-test-from-the-cli/65256621#65256621 . And yes, xcodebuild is still needed (not an xcodeproj tho!), there is no way (12/2020 yet?) to restrict your compilation for only one platform using `swift build` and friends, sadly :(